# Disable(readonly) a checkbox which in inside a Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datatable

I'm quiet new to Jquery and working on an MVC project.
I'm getting data from the DB and displaying it in a Jquery DataTable.
I have checkbox column inside the DataTable.I set the value of the checkbox depending upon the value of Status which is one of the fields of my table. I want to make it readonly checkbox.In other words I want
to disable it.
Here's the code where I'm setting the value of checkbox depending upon the value of Status(one of the fields) from the table.

```
{
                "targets": -3,
                "data": null,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return data.Status== true ? '<input type=\"checkbox\" name="chk1" checked value=' + data.Status + '>' : '<input type=\"checkbox\" name="chk2"  value=' + data.Status+ '>';
                }
            }
```

Please help me to disable the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `disabled` to the checkbox you want to disable.

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled />
```

Comment: Thanks @roullie , it worked , such a simple thing , silly me.